# Other users in Sandbox cannot log in

Tags: sandbox

I have a Professional edition of SalesForce where I have one Sandbox license. I created one Sandbox and I'm able to log in as the administrator but other users cannot log in to the sandbox.

They are using the url test.salesforce.com to log in with their login as testuser@testaccount.com.dev and the same password as they had in the production system.

Is there something that can be done to fix this or is this because only one user is allowed to log in to the sandbox?

Comment: Have you checked their login history?

Comment: When you are logged in as admin in the sandbox, go to manage Users and see if anything looks fishy. Are they active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one straightforward approach is to send a reset password for those users who are having issue logging inot sandbox. This can be done easily when you actually logged into sandbox as sys admin. Simple and easy.

so, go to Users, select the users you want and click Reset Password.

Comment: I've reset the password for the user and tried logging in with the new password, and it still does not work.

Comment: one way you can check is go to users page and click the login link for an user which you think having issue in loggin in...On clicking it, you should be automatically logged in as that user and if not something you need to check 1. user licenses, 2. ip restrictions, 3. the correct sandbox name suffixed with user name 4. account active or not 5. login hours

Comment: I am able to log in to the other users from the Manage Users page. But I am not able to log in to the users directly from test.salesforce.com.

Comment: can you see the user's detail and check if the account locked or not? it should not be locked...

Comment: Ah, the user I was trying to log in with was 'Frozen' since I'm using the Winter '14 release! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome..Now you are good to go...

Answer (score 0):

If the sandbox was burned prior to those user accounts being created in production, then the users would not have access. Sandboxes do not mirror production, they are a snapshot of your production instance in time.

Comment: The sandbox was just burned and these user accounts were already in production when the sandbox was refreshed and activated.

Comment: greenstork i too getting the same issue, as i not able to login into sandbox with the user credentials which i used to login into production...what could be the issue?

Comment: the sandbox name must be appended to the end of their username. Can you look at your users to see that they exist, with the correct username?

Comment: The user is indeed logging in with the sandbox name appended to their username. They are logging in with the correct username.